# How to set Facebook album privacy with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I would like to know if it's possible to set the privacy setting for a specific Facebook album with RestFB Java library ?

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album you can't.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176987712426506/, it was filed as a bug that has now been fixed. I haven't tested this yet myself so cannot confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You can set privacy settings when the album is created.

Currently, you can not update the settings, nor can you delete an existing album via API, in case you wanted to just delete and recreate it as a work around.
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17111

When you create the album, you need to create a privacy object and include it as a parameter in the POST request, which is a JSON-encoded string that is described more clearly in the documentation of a Post object here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for the moment. On the main API page on Facebook, you can see which operations are possible. Sadly, updates are not one of them:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1):

curl https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums -F 'access_token=xxx' -F 'name=my album' -F 'privacy={"value":"ALL_FRIENDS"}'

Comment: Supplying the json object doesn't work. The created album has privacy 'Friends'.
-----------
FB.api('/me/albums', 'post', {name:'Test album', message:'Test album for testing purpose', privacy: {'value':'EVERYONE'}}, function(response) { console.log(response); });