# Changing privacy settings using Facebook SDK in csharp for windowsphone

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

If I use these parameters and upload image or update status then it is uploading/updating in Audience as Public. But i need to change Audience to only me.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "message", FacebookMessage },
    { "privacy", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "value", "ALL_FRIENDS" }
        }
    }
};
```

I tried replacing "ALL_FRIENDS" as "ONLY_ME" but error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `SELF` in the value for `value` key of the `privacy` dictionary.

```
 {"value", "SELF"}
```

Please see this question as well:  [facebook c# api, video getting uploaded but its PUBLIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038867/facebook-c-sharp-api-video-getting-uploaded-but-its-public)

Comment: Yup i should wait for few minutes to mark it as answer, and can help me where did you get that solution.

Comment: I Google the questions which I find interesting. I would read  documentations, blogs  or try the code etc. That is my way of learning new stuff.

Comment: can you suggest me with few links

Comment: [This blog](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-writing-your-first-facebook-application), [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880413/how-to-set-facebook-album-privacy-with-graph-api)