# picture upload on facebook

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8.1

hi  i am trying to upload images from my wp8.1 app to facebook but one of the issues is that pictures posted are  visible to only  me unless i amnually change it from facebook . i want to post them automatically for public to view . here is my code :

```
 var postParams = new
        {
            access_token = ObjFBHelper.AccessToken,
            message = "My message",
            source = pic,



        };

  try
     {
       dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await    fbclient.PostTaskAsync("me/photos",postParams);
     var responseresult = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageDialog ErrMsg = new MessageDialog("Error Ocuured!");

        }
```

Comment: it's windows phone 8.1 app so c# the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "message", FacebookMessage },
    { "privacy", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "value", "ALL_FRIENDS" }
        }
    }
};
```

I found this on stackoverflow. Maybe it helps you too?

From: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202994/changing-privacy-settings-using-facebook-sdk-in-csharp-for-windowsphone)

Comment: when i upload any picture from my laptop it gets public while any pic from my app gets as only to me so how can change it. do i need to send some permission ?

Comment: var postParams = new
            {
                access_token = ObjFBHelper.AccessToken,
                message = "My message",
                source = pic,
                privacy = ALL_FRIENDS,





            };

it gives an error that all_friends doesn't exist in current context

Comment: @Kam, please have a look at my updated code. Maybe you can adjust it, and it will work :)

Comment: You can accept my answer as correct one if it helped you :)